# Error in code, NullPointException

Tags: arrays, nullpointerexception

I am working on a program for class due today at midnight and I just can't figure why it's giving me this Null Point Exception error.  I would really appreciate if you guys can look at my code and help me out.

The goal of the project is as follows..

- Program Statement: Write a Payroll class that uses the following arrays as fields:

  - employeeId - an array of 7 integers to hold employee id numbers.  The array field should be initialized with the following numbers:

    1. 5658845
    2. 4520125
    3. 7895122
    4. 8777541
    5. 8451277
    6. 1302850
    7. 7580489
  - hours - An array of seven integers to hold the number of hours worked by each employee
  - payRate - An array of seven doubles to hold each employee's hourly rate.
  - wages - An array of seven doubles to hold each employee's gross wages.

  The class should relate the data in each array through the subscripts.  For example, the number in element 0 of the hours array should be the number of hours worked by the employee whose ID number is stored in Element 0 of the employeeId array.  That same employees pay rate should be stored in Element 0 of the payRate array.  In addition to the appropriate accessor and mutator methods, the class should have a method that accepts an employee's id number as an argument and returns the gross pay for that employee.  Demonstrate the class in a complete program that displays each employee number and asks the user to enter the employee's hours and pay rate.  It should then display each employee's id number and gross wages.

  - Input Validation : Do not accept negative values for numbers and numbers less than 6.00 for pay rate.

---

```
int[] employeeId;
int[] hours;
double[] payRate;
double[] wages;

Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public ParrishPayroll(int[] ids){

    employeeId = new int[ids.length];
    // Copy the values in ids
    for (int index = 0; index < ids.length; index++)
        employeeId[index] = ids[index];

    System.out.println("Employee ID's");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employeeId));

    System.out.println("Please enter the id number you would like to edit.");
        int input = kboard.nextInt();

        if(input == 5658845){
            int index = 0;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else if(input == 4520125){
            int index = 1;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else if(input == 7895122){
            int index = 2;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else if(input == 8777541){
            int index = 3;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else if(input == 8451277){
            int index = 4;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else if(input == 1302850){
            int index = 5;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else if(input == 7580489){
            int index = 6;
            setHours(index);
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID number!");

            }
}//end startSequence

public void setHours(int i){

    System.out.println("How many hours were worked?");
    hours[i] = kboard.nextInt();    
        if(hours[i] < 0){
            System.out.println("Please input a positive number.");
            kboard.nextInt(hours[i]);
            setPayRate(i);
        }
        else
            setPayRate(i);

}

public void setPayRate(int index){

    int input = index;

    System.out.println("What is the employee's pay rate?");
    payRate[input] = kboard.nextDouble();
        if(payRate[input] < 0){
            System.out.println("Please input a positive number.");
            payRate[input] = kboard.nextDouble();
            calcWages(input);
        }
        else if(payRate[index] < 6.00){
            System.out.println("Wages must be higher than $6.00.");
            payRate[input] = kboard.nextDouble();
            calcWages(input);
        }
}

public void calcWages(int index){

    int input = index;

    wages[input] = hours[input] * payRate[input];

}


public void getGross(int i){

    int input = i;

    if(input == 5658845){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[0]);
        }
    else if(input == 4520125){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[1]);
        }
    else if(input == 7895122){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[2]);
        }
    else if(input == 8777541){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[3]);
        }
    else if(input == 8451277){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[4]);
        }
    else if(input == 1302850){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[5]);
        }
    else if(input == 7580489){
        System.out.print("Employee number: " + input + " wages: " + wages[6]);
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid ID number!");
        getGross(input);
        }


   }


public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] idlist = {5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489};

    ParrishPayroll user1 = new ParrishPayroll(idlist);

    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What employee would you like to see the gross wages for?");
    int i = kboard.nextInt();
    user1.getGross(i);    

}
```

Comment: Whenever you are debugging exceptions you should look at the stack trace. It will tell you exactly which line caused the error. Can you edit your question and post the stack trace?

Comment: How many hours were worked?
10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ParrishPayroll.setHours(ParrishPayroll.java:91)
 at ParrishPayroll.<init>(ParrishPayroll.java:64)
 at ParrishPayrollDemo.main(ParrishPayrollDemo.java:11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not initializing the `hours`, `payRate` or `wages` variables, which means they are all null. When you call, say, `hours[i] = kboard.nextInt()` it will throw a NullPointerException because you can't set the *i* th element of `null`.

Make sure you have a line like `hours = new int[whatever]` before you try to use the `hours` variable (same for the other two). You've got it right for `employeeId`, so follow that pattern.

Comment: I posted what my console spits out, I'm going to try your suggestion right now.